# Как сделать большую выборку, используя только один запрос к mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

В таблице есть поле category и поле answer. Поле category может иметь только три значения, например, cat1,cat2 и cat3. Answer имеет значение либо 0, либо 1 (т.е. получен ответ или нет). Запрос должен вернуть результат, содержащий количество записей, сгруппированный по значению поля category плюс количество тех же записей (аналогично сгруппированных), у который значение поля answer = 0.

Это можно сделать двумя запросами:

```
SELECT COUNT(1),category FROM table GROUP BY category;
SELECT COUNT(1),category FROM table WHERE answer='0' GROUP BY category;
```

Можно ли эти запросы объединить в один? В общем, пока у меня ничего не вышло.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

И почему все забывают про `IF`?

```
SELECT  `category`, COUNT(*) as `count_all`, SUM( IF(`answer` =0, 1, 0) ) as `count_answer_null` FROM  `table` GROUP BY  `category`
```

Comment: @Равнодушный, только что  сам научился пользоваться if и вдруг ваш ответ! Спасибо! Тем более, что я упростил вопрос.На самом деле answer у меня может быть либо строкой, либо пустой строкой. Вы мне здорово помогли!

Answer (score 0):

[UNION поможет.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

Comment: Пока что не помогает...

Comment: В таблице есть три записи для cat1 - две со значением answer 1, одна - 0. Что должен вернуть запрос?

Comment: cat1 - общее число=3; без ответа=1.

cat2 - общее число... ... и т.д.